# Disable touch event on document in Firefox 4 for Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I can disable touch events on android's webkit browser by the code below.

```
$(document).bind('touchmove', function(e){epreventDefault();});
```

But it seem not working on the new Firefox 4 for Android. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).bind('MozTouchMove', function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

I would assume this should work. The difference is that Mozilla calls their touch events different names:

```
MozTouchDown: "Sent when the user begins a screen touch action."
MozTouchMove: "Sent when the user moves his finger on the touch screen."
MozTouchUp:   "Sent when the user lifts his finger off the screen."
```

P.S. It's "e.preventDefault();" ... you forgot the "." in your code.

Comment: I try this. But seem it not working and the page still scroll after disable the "moztouchmove".

Comment: Basically, i also want to disable the gesture to show the tab bar/toolbar. Now, they will show when swipe left/right.